# Simple Search form and no results for existing entries

Tags: search, simple-search

EE 2.7.3 and Simple Search form which looks like

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="products" search_in="everywhere" result_page="home/search"}
          <label for="keywords">Search</label>
          <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" placeholder="Search" />
          <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button>
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

and result template:

```
<div class="row default">
Search results:
{exp:search:search_results}
{title}
{/exp:search:search_results}
</div>
```

for testing I have type in part of the title from one, existing entry in the Products channel. Unfortunately it gives me `Your search did not return any results` or returns one search result which is not related to search keyword.

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case it required to add `status` to search tag

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="products" search_in="everywhere" status="open" result_page="home/search"}
```

and I was able to see search results.